# Saving City id to Db and getting name of city at retrieving data?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a `person` class which has `Name, CNIC, Gender, City` properties.

At time of saving data to DB all is fine.

I populate a drop down with cities and user can select city and the ID of city will be saved in `tblperson`'s `City` column which has foreign key constraint to `tblcity` `ID` column.

Now, when I want to retrieve data from `tblPerson` I get everything fine, and I'm able to show data in the textboxes albeit I get city id and not city name

But I want to get the name of the city displayed in the textbox. How can I do that?

What I think I should do is:

1. Create a new method in city class `getCityName`.
2. Pass id of the city from `person.City` to `getCityName` method of city class.
3. Get city name from `tblCity` table in the database

Is this approach right? If not then what's the better way to do this?

Comment: Inner join to the City tables and get the name instead

Comment: The above comment is valid assuming that you never delete any row from City table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to write the appropriate SQL query. The JOIN statement allows you to retrieve data from more than one table and the SELECT statement could return this data.

In your case the query should be something like this

```
SELECT p.Name, p.CNIC , p.Gender, p.City, c.CityName
FROM tblperson p LEFT JOIN  tblCity c ON p.City = c.ID
```

(Of course I have guessed the column name that contains the city name.
If it is different then you could change it)

You could find some interesting documentation about JOIN using your favorite search engine.
This, for example, is from [Microsoft Technet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191517(v=sql.105).aspx)

Comment: yes i understand about joins. but how would i store retreived city name which will be in string and my person.city attribute is in int?

Comment: As you can see, the query contains also the p.City field. The CityName is just for display. If you use a DataGridView or some kind of grid, you should simply hide the City column and let your users look at  the CityName column but you have full access to the same row City hidden field

Comment: actually i'm using layerd architecture. i'm filling person object with retreived data at dal layer and sending data back to bll and from there to pl. i'm not using gridview in this.

Comment: OK but you could easily change this architecture adding the CityName field in your Person class. Of course, your original idea could work but that approach causes a second trip to retrieve data from your db for every record. This could easily become a performance problem when the data set grows. So you need to make compromises and adding a CityName field to the person class is the easy solution. (Another one could be to load all CityName and CityID in memory and search the CityName from this data set)

Comment: adding city name to the class seems Better. but at registration time the cityName property will be left empty. is it not considered bad?

Comment: No, I think that there is no evil in that. It is an internal logic that should be handled by your business logic layer and totally unknown to the lower level layer